# Вывести посты за последние 5 лет, начиная с текущей даты

Tags: php, wordpress, post, дата

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить простую задачу. Есть стандартный запрос в php на вывод постов. Надо добавить условие, чтобы дата поста для вывода была не старше 5 лет с текущей даты.

```
<ol class="su-posts su-posts-list-loop">
<?php
// Posts are found
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        global $post;
?>
<li id="su-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="su-post"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php
    }
}
// Posts not found
else {
}
?>
</ol>
```

Comment: как вы получаете посты? добавьте в вопрос код

Comment: Ну просто в запрос к БД добавляете условие, а дальше выводите как выводится

Comment: Как вы сами пытались решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете изменить запрос используя фильтр, этот код нужно добавить в `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'su/shortcode/posts/wp_query_args', function( $args ) {
    $args['data_query'] = [
        'after' => '5 year ago',
    ];

    return $args;
} );
```

если вы не хотите изменять условие выборки, то вы можете добавить условие  в цикл

```
while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
    $posts->the_post();
    global $post;

    if ( get_post_time() < (time() - YEAR_IN_SECONDS * 5) ) {
        continue;
    }
    ?>
    <li id="su-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="su-post"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Можете уточнить, в какое место надо добавить код? я добавил после global $post и у меня сломался шаблон

Comment: @Zanuda247 это не нужно добавлять в цикл, это нужно добавить в условие выборки. добавьте ваш код для получения постов в вопрос и покажу как его нужно изменить

Comment: <ol class="su-posts su-posts-list-loop">
<?php
// Posts are found
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
  $posts->the_post();
  global $post;
?>
<li id="su-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="su-post"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php
 }
}
// Posts not found
else {
}
?>
</ol>

Comment: не нужно добавлять цикл вы его и так уже добавили в вопрос, добавьте код через который вы присваиваете значение переменной $posts

Comment: if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['posts'] ) ) {
  global $posts;
 }
 $original_posts = $posts;
 // Filter args
 $args = apply_filters( 'su/shortcode/posts/wp_query_args', $args, $atts );
 // Query posts
 $posts = new WP_Query( $args );
 // Load the template
 $output = su_shortcode_posts_include_template( $atts, $posts );
 // Return original posts
 $posts = $original_posts;
 // Reset the query
 wp_reset_postdata();
 su_query_asset( 'css', 'su-shortcodes' );
 return $output;
}
это имеете ввиду? это значение присваивает код плагина

Comment: а можно обойтись коррекцией цикла? мне выборка за 5 лет нужна только в части контента, в остальных местах весь архив. Я для разных целей корректировал только циклы.

Comment: @Zanuda247 обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сработало!